# pass value from button value to input text

Tags: php, html

[image]

May I Ask About Angular
I am a beginner and
I need to pass a value from Button to Input text 
I have many Buttons like

When I Press abutton the Text Value will change

Comment: Are you using Angular JS ?

Comment: yes I Am Using Angular JS & junior

Comment: post real code and not an image of it

Comment: <html>
<button type="button" id="button_1" name="button_1">One</button>
<button type="button" id="button_2" name="button_1">Two</button>
<button type="button" id="button_3" name="button_1">Three</button>
<p>The Value is:</p>
<input type="text"  name="output" id="output_text"/>
</html>

Comment: in the question, not in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angular js then following thing can help you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValue = function(number){
    $scope.myValue = number;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click=setValue('One')>One</button>
    <button ng-click=setValue('Two')>Two</button>
    <button ng-click=setValue('Three')>Three</button>
    <input value="{{myValue}}" />
  </div>  
</body>
```